# JSON request object titanium does not post

Tags: json, titanium, titanium-mobile

Here is my post request:

```
exports.APIPostRequest = function(url, JSONObj, callback, errorCallback) {
    Ti.API.info('Get Request is called');
    var req = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload : callback,
        onerror : errorCallback,
        timeout : 60000
    });
    req.open("POST", url);
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    //JSON object goes into send method.
    req.send(JSONObj);
};
```

after I make my request.

After making a post request , it does not send the JSON object.

{"facebook_token":"dasdaddasd","date_of_birth":"503435231.0","gender":"male","ethnicity":"","description":"ls lsls ","nickname":"ffsfs"}

Now when I post it , the api complains that it is not in the right format:

```
{
    "facdebook_scriptioken":"BAACMVus3xYsdwqdAdkSGzrr0vFscmDK=IuA%20zW4QYlovSziJJCmrpFtyNl8edfR4hVU1ZAv60yHqFP7yEJ8g6SSrmvibt9Grw7L%27xIsALM0mVWsZBTRcYAIPzy%23npG6SKE12sAcno0kWVhg5LZAljqM0ZBzUtsZA8W9zife%21&publiGdWLc_name=0wbjEx4xGU&genwAJiZAder=malwFF9ZBmUe&ev8gGjDgZDZD",
    "thnickname":"jsm",
    "ity=&date_of_birth": =503435231,
    "gender":"male",
    "public_name": false,
    ".0&body_type":"thin",
    "devi=&facebook_token": "ad=CAAUYyAuheuQrc0BAKRqYidhw2gFK1GSmniDZddadwoKblpLIVZC1fwTpfhwugRIabmiZBZANfh0ZAV67I9QowuehfiwhfweqonD5IaRZApgWkgfhpODKJ2KGLIdwWt89KyCZBy9UMPmjIbZBGxN64IZCkZAFLMk6KapBHqU4no98MoSZBtqRHguYJnImQ8tV1bEFfSZBqzShaeiw"
    "sD9kAfTN2F3xethZAXqTfEob2vqUVk5pXsAqsYZD&nicity":"",
    "dknamesc=Pription":"thices is m%dadad"
}
```

Totally scrambled , why is this happening, cheers?

```
  {
        "facebook_t": "Bdadadadsadadadad",
        "niame": "jsm",
        "publethnic_name": false,
        "body_itype": "thAsan",
        "devscrice_ptioken": "aduhI loveu my lidhwihwufefwpfhwu!",
        "nifhwucknamehf": "Priwhfwncefhwhifwufhss eiw",
        "ethnpublicity_name": "0",
        "bodescripy_tionype": "Prefer not thiso dis mclose."
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it JSON.Stringify and let me know if still complains the same

```
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(JSONObj))
```

Thanks

Comment: It is still complaining.

Comment: just double checked in a validator its correct JSON, the problem is all the fields are messed up

Comment: Found the problem, it was a problem with the server side. This is the correct way of sending JSON data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For sending POST requests (form data) you will have to set the content-type header to

```
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```